# android-parsing nested json Objects

Tags: android, json, nested, android-ion

i have to implement json data in my application. but i can't get it how to fetch data from server. i am using ION library.

```
{
"search": [{
    "id": "5454003",
    "description": "Larger Than Life",
    "url": "http://audiojungle.net/item/larger-than-life/5454003",
    "type": "item",
    "sales": "1469",
    "rating": "5",
    "item_info": {
        "id": "5454003",
        "item": "Larger Than Life",
        "url": "http://audiojungle.net/item/larger-than-life/5454003",
        "user": "pinkzebra",
        "thumbnail": "https://0.s3.envato.com/files/67162834/upbeatsongwinner2.jpg",
        "sales": "1469",
        "rating": "5",
        "rating_decimal": "4.96",
        "cost": "18.00",
        "preview_type": "audio",
        "preview_url": "https://0.s3.envato.com/files/94250640/preview.mp3",
        "length": "2:35"
    }
} ] }
```

this is my json data. i want to display in my application data like "cost" , "user" ect. but i didn't get it. ion code is here,

```
Ion.with(this)
            .load("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/search:audiojungle,,happy.json")
            .asJsonObject().setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception arg0, JsonObject data) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

so if anybody knows then please help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: from object data get array "search", then take one of its elements(or iterate the array), then the element "item_info", then take element "cost" or "user" ... and why it gets +1? this question is typical "how to parse json with X library" answered many times here

Comment: but i really didn't get any idea about that. please give me any reference.

Comment: your JSON data is invalid Fotomat  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 23 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: ok: check which json library is used by ION, then find documentation to this library, read it(or google for samples), write the code ... simply enough?

Comment: Handling Json with the Gson library is easier IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** The first info that you posted was has some misleading information, i checked the answer that you posted and i have a working code for you,

code:

```
Ion.with(this)
        .load("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/search:audiojungle,,happy.json")
        .asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
        try {
            parseJson(new JSONObject(result));
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

To parse the response data:

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject result) {

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("search");
        for(int a=0;a<jsonArray.length();a++){

            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("id"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("description"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("url"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("type"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("sales"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("rating"));

            // JSON data with in JSONObject "item_info"
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("id"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("item"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("url"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("user"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("thumbnail"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("sales"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("rating"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("rating_decimal"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("cost"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("preview_type"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("preview_url"));
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info").getString("length"));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

- Remember to use JSONArray(org.json.JSONArray) and JSONObject(org.json.JSONObject) form the org.json libary not JsonArray(com.google.gson.JsonArray;) or JsonObject(com.google.gson.JsonObject) from the com.google.gson library, it get things mess up;
- To make things easy paste response here http://json.parser.online.fr/ to see which one is a jsonobject or array

Comment: @NikPastagia what do you mean with "get multiple values for single object"

Comment: i mean to say item_info object is repeated in every array index value... so i want to get every index value of array...

Comment: @NikPastagia form what i understand that you only want item_info data from each array than you have to use jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONObject("item_info") in the loop. you will get the compleate item_info object of each array.

Comment: @NikPastagia gilbert92sarip@gmail.com

Comment: Hello does this mean that i can Set my setters in the for loop to bind to my Recyclerview ?, how can i bind that Json data to my RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

**Process :**

```
JsonArray searchArray = getJsonArray("search");
JsonObject index_0_Object= searchArray.getJsonObject("index_0");
JsonObject infoObject = index_0_Object.getJsonObject("item_info");
String id = infoObject.getString("id");

System.out.pritnln(id);
```

**Edited** :

first : you have to find "search" array , after it use indexing to get its object , so now you have    JsonObject , from it get "item_info" object , from there you can find "id" object .

Comment: also not working for me... your answer is for GSON.. every time i used it not getting any value... simple use JSONObject or JSONArray not use JsonArray..

Comment: buddy i have added this as a process , try to parse according to this answer .

Comment: here, no method like getJsonArray("search").

Answer (score 0):

```
> yes i got it...

    Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/search:audiojungle,,happy.json")
                .asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception arg0, String data) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(data);
                            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("search");

                            for ( int i = 0 ; i < jArray.size() ; i++ )
                            {
                                JSONObject jObject_0 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject jObj = jObject_0.getJSONObject("id");
                                Log.e("id : ",id+"");
                            } 
                            //JSONObject jObject_0 = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
                            //JSONObject jObj = jObject_0.getJSONObject("item_info");
                            //cost.setText(jObj.getString("cost"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

> but this returns only one value. i want to multiple value according to array list.
```

check your logs .

Comment: use jArray.size() , and use forloop .

Comment: every time it gives me single value.

Comment: there is only one object present in your json .