# parsing nested json object in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

How do I parse Json data when the Json response data is returned in nested Json object form.

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874961/6458268) which shows how to get only one piece of data. As I want whole data set it is not useful for me.

It said:

```
JSONObject jMainObject = null;
    try {
        jMainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject apiGroupsObject = jMainObject.getJSONObject("apiGroups");
        JSONObject affiliateObject = apiGroupsObject.getJSONObject("affiliate"); 
        JSONObject apiListingsObject = affiliateObject.getJSONObject("apiListings");
        JSONObject bags_wallets_beltsObject = apiListingsObject.getJSONObject("bags_wallets_belts");
        JSONObject availableVariantsObject = bags_wallets_beltsObject.getJSONObject("availableVariants");
        JSONObject versionObject = availableVariantsObject.getJSONObject("v0.1.0");
        System.out.println(versionObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Json returned data which I want to parse is coming [from here](http://www.clusterdev.com/flipkart-api-demo/home-example.html).

Can anyone help me to solve my problem about how to parse this type of data as I’m new so I don’t know how to parse nested Json object data. Perhaps I can use Gson for it? But I also don't know how to use that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android-parsing nested json Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653215/android-parsing-nested-json-objects)

Comment: Use gson. It is very fast and easy way to perse data from json. Remember that the object name must be the same as the key. Gson lib use reflection to parse data.

Comment: how to use Gson lib?

Comment: check these.... for all System.out.println(apiGroupsObject );
System.out.println(affiliateObject); etc... see what the prob...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do it like this, hope it will help you, tested    

JSONObject objresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject objapiGroups = objresponse.getJSONObject("apiGroups");
                    JSONObject objaffiliate = objapiGroups.getJSONObject("affiliate");
                    JSONObject objapiListings = objaffiliate.getJSONObject("apiListings");

                    Iterator iterator = objapiListings.keys();
                    int i=0;
                    Catagory=new String[objapiListings.length()];
                    while(iterator.hasNext()){
                        String key = (String)iterator.next();
                        JSONObject issue = objapiListings.getJSONObject(key);

                        //  get id from  issue
                        Catagory[i] = issue.optString("apiName");
                        i++;
                    }
                    JSONObject[] objcat = new JSONObject[Catagory.length];
                    CatagoryName=new String[Catagory.length];
                    Url=new String[Catagory.length];
                    for(int j=0;j<Catagory.length;j++)
                    {
                        objcat[j]=objapiListings.getJSONObject(Catagory[j]);

                        CatagoryName[j]=objcat[j].getJSONObject("availableVariants").getJSONObject("v1.1.0").getString("resourceName");
                        Url[j]=objcat[j].getJSONObject("availableVariants").getJSONObject("v1.1.0").getString("get");

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of serializing/deserialize - don't do it yourself.
Use **compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'** instead.
It is the google annotation based deserializer.
[Here is some tutorial on how to use it.](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try your parsing using volley library .It's a big data so always use optJson object for avoiding null.This is small piece of code .Hope it will help you.
  String title = response.getString("title");
String   description = response.getString("description");


JSONObject objApiGrp = response.optJSONObject("apiGroups");
if(objApiGrp != null && objApiGrp.size()>0)
{
    JSONObject objaffiliate = objApiGrp.optJSONObject("affiliate");

    for(int i=0 ; i<objaffiliate.size() ; i++)
{


JSONObject objapiListings = objaffiliate.optJSONObject("apiListings");
for(int i=0 ; i<objapiListings.size() ; i++)
{

//      parse all objects


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all separate objects to get whole key data value.
Like this:

```
JSONObject jMainObject = null;
try {
    jMainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject apiGroupsObject = jMainObject.getJSONObject("apiGroups");
    JSONObject affiliateObject = apiGroupsObject.getJSONObject("affiliate"); 
    JSONObject apiListingsObject = affiliateObject.getJSONObject("apiListings");
    JSONObject bags_wallets_beltsObject = apiListingsObject.getJSONObject("bags_wallets_belts");
    JSONObject availableVariantsObject = bags_wallets_beltsObject.getJSONObject("availableVariants");
    JSONObject versionObject = availableVariantsObject.getJSONObject("v0.1.0");
    System.out.println(versionObject);

    JSONObject fragrances = apiListingsObject.getJSONObject("fragrances");
    availableVariantsObject = bags_wallets_beltsObject.getJSONObject("availableVariants");
    versionObject = availableVariantsObject.getJSONObject("v0.1.0");
    System.out.println(versionObject);

    JSONObject tv_video_accessories = apiListingsObject.getJSONObject("tv_video_accessories");
    availableVariantsObject = bags_wallets_beltsObject.getJSONObject("availableVariants");
    versionObject = availableVariantsObject.getJSONObject("v0.1.0");
    System.out.println(versionObject);

    JSONObject camera_accessories = apiListingsObject.getJSONObject("camera_accessories");
    availableVariantsObject = bags_wallets_beltsObject.getJSONObject("availableVariants");
    versionObject = availableVariantsObject.getJSONObject("v0.1.0");
    System.out.println(versionObject);

    JSONObject sports_fitness = apiListingsObject.getJSONObject("sports_fitness");
    availableVariantsObject = bags_wallets_beltsObject.getJSONObject("availableVariants");
    versionObject = availableVariantsObject.getJSONObject("v0.1.0");
    System.out.println(versionObject);

    // Make and use object like this for all key Values.

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All Keys are different so, not able to use loop for that. otherwise code is optimize with loop.